# How do I reference a relative path in Jupyter-book

Tags: jupyter, python-sphinx, jupyterbook

In Jupyter-book, I am creating a _toc.yml file. I have something like -

```
- caption: Tutorials
  chapters:
  - file: ../../notebooks/some_notebook
```

I get the exception -

```
home/code/nwb_datajoint/docs/web-doc/intro.md:: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document '../../notebooks/some_notebook' [etoc.ref]
looking for now-outdated files... none found
```

How do I reference a relative directory in in _toc.yml's parent directory?

Comment: [jupyterhub](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jupyterhub/info) is a multi-user server providing a jupyter interface. it doesn't seem to be relevant to this question - if that's true can you drop the tag?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thanks for being considerate and telling me this as opposed to showing lack of manners and taking it out without telling me.

Comment: Sure thing! FYI though there are a *ton* of questions that need editing on this site, and most of the time users don't properly edit their own questions. We're trying to answer your question and also leave a useful set of information for other users who come along with your same question, so when people edit questions they're not trying to be rude, they're just trying to make their way throuh a never-ending mountain of curation work ;)

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? I am having the identical problem and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @NicoBako. No. What I did was add code in the config file to copy over the notebooks into my Sphinx folder; as part of build. I have share code if you need more assistance.

Comment: @Phil can you please share the code

Comment: Out of curiosity : why not use the absolute path? What is your use-case? I use absolute paths, i.e. in the `_toc.yml` file : `- file: notebooks/some_notebook.ipynb`.